# how to get the following output of the code snippet?

Tags: javascript, object, output

I have been asked this question in an interview. How to solve this? The object and consoles statements are mentioned. I am not getting how to implement the function findPath?
[image: Code snippet]

Comment: Well maybe this is helpful: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-object-from-a-specific-path-with-vanilla-js/

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) Post CODE, not PICTURES of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
class Obj {
  constructor() {
    this.data = {
      a: {
        b: {
          c: 12
        }
      }
    };
  }

  findPath = (str) => {
    let sol = this.data;
    for (let key of str.split(".")) {
      sol = sol[key];
      if (!sol) {
        return undefined;
      }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(sol);
  };
}

let obj = new Obj();
console.log(obj.findPath("a.b.c"));
console.log(obj.findPath("a.b"));
console.log(obj.findPath("a.b.d"));
console.log(obj.findPath("a.c"));
console.log(obj.findPath("a.b.c.d"));
console.log(obj.findPath("a.b.c.d.e"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    }
  }
}

obj.findPath = function(path) {
  const keys = path.split('.');
  return keys.reduce((currentPath, key) => {
    return currentPath && currentPath[key]
  }, this) 
}

console.log(obj.findPath('a'))
console.log(obj.findPath('a.b'))
console.log(obj.findPath('a.b.c'))
console.log(obj.findPath('a.b.c.d'))
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do it

```js
var obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 1
    }
  }
}
function findPath(path) {
  const paths = path.split('.');
  let innerObj = {...obj};
  for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    innerObj = innerObj && innerObj[paths[i]] || null;
  }
  return innerObj;
}

console.log(findPath("a.b.c"));
console.log(findPath("a.b"));
console.log(findPath("a.b.d"));
console.log(findPath("a.c"));
console.log(findPath("a.b.c.d"));
console.log(findPath("a.b.c.d.e"));
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please test your code when posting

Comment: Why are you storing the object in a new object?

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach

```js
const obj = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 12,
    },
  },
  k: null,
};

const testFunc = (obj, k) => {
  const arr = k.split(".");
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    obj = obj[arr[i]];
  }
  return obj;
};

console.log(testFunc(obj, "k")); //null
console.log(testFunc(obj, "a.b.c")); //12
console.log(testFunc(obj, "a.b.c.d")); //undefined
console.log(testFunc(obj, "f")); //undefined
```